# AngularJS simple page counter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I have this in my html template.  I want the button to fire the showMore function when clicked.

```
<button ng-click="showMore(secondPage)">Show More</button>
```

This is the controller. I'm not sure why $scope.nextPage will increment up everywhere except for at $scope.secondPage. I want `$scope.secondPage` to do fire on the first click `Entry.query({page: 2})` then fire `Entry.query({page: 3})` on the next click. But right now it keeps firing page 2.

```
@MainController = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.query({page: 1})

  $scope.nextPage = 2
  $scope.secondPage = Entry.query({page: $scope.nextPage})

  $scope.showMore = (secondPage) ->
    i = 0
    while i < secondPage.length
      $scope.entries.push(secondPage[i])
      i++
    $scope.nextPage++
    console.log("nextpage" + $scope.nextPage)    

]
```

I am using coffeescript. I don't fully understand why the page number in $scope.secondPage is not incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
<button ng-click="showMore()">Show More</button>

@MainController = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->

  $scope.entries = []
  current_page = 1

  $scope.showMore = ->
    on_success = (entries)->
      $scope.entries = $scope.entries.concat entries
      current_page = current_page + 1
    Entry.query {page: current_page}, on_success

  $scope.showMore()
]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer. So I don't just blindly accept this answer. I'll try to make sense of it.  The main difference here is that you are calling Entry.query inside the $scope.showMore function which keeps the incremented current_page in the same scope as the current_page argument in Entry.query {page: current_page}